# Are cross-legged digital keyboard stands comfortable while playing seated

Tags: keyboard, digital-piano, stand

I'm buying my first digital keyboard, more specifically a Yamaha NP12. I intend to play seated and I wonder if a cross legged stand is comfortable.

Would I have enough room for my legs/knees or should I buy a table style stand. I'm 5, 9.

Comment: Minor nit: that's a digital keyboard, as a more general class.  I've always limited "digital piano" to setups which include pedals.  I dunno if that's a common distinction or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knee room isn't a problem.   Stability may be.  But I've been gigging (literally) the same X-stands for about 40 years, and they haven't let me down yet!

They're the type with a brace though.  I don't trust the ones where ALL the strain is taken on the pivot point.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, cross stands are always a touch unstable, because of the way they're constructed - the connections to the legs are in the center of the leg, and usually only only attached by one bolt (which has, as its only function in life, the desire to be unscrewed). I had one at church for holding a secondary keyboard, and I ended up screwing it to the stage to keep it still.

I prefer Z-type stands. They cost a little more, but are much more stable, and have a higher weight bearing capacity (usually 200lbs+, compared to less than 100lbs for a X-stand)

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using cross stands after one collapsed at a gig. Not easy playing keys whilst kneeling! Always use a stand with legs splayed out left and right. bit heavier and bukier, but never lets me down - literally!But for a permanent cheap and cheerful stand, it'll do. Enough room for knees usually - although thinking about it - I have other sorts of stands in the studio - no X stands.